# Jruby: How to use third party java library?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

I want to use java third party qr code libary https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen library for generating qr code.

Please guide me as i don't know how to integrate java library in jruby.

Comment: did you try my answer? did you make any progress?

Comment: Christian - Actually i am busy with some other work.. but i will definitely reply you in next two days. thanks for your answer.

Comment: I modified the answer with finer control of the png generations. I've tried it with jruby, nice 3rd party QR library ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick in this case is **to find how to properly import the 3rd party libs**.

- Please download the needed jars using any dependency system (I use ant with ivy).
- This will download 5 jars based on the qr code library you mentioned: core-2.0.jar core-3.1.0.jar javase-2.0.jar javase-3.1.0.jar jfreesvg-2.1.jar

**build.xml** for ant:

```
<project xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" name="" default="retrieve">
  <!--setproxy proxyhost="" proxyport="" proxyuser="" proxypassword=""/-->
  <target name="retrieve">
    <ivy:retrieve/>
  </target>
</project>
```

**ivy.xml** for ivy:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0" >
  <info organisation="" module=""/>
  <dependencies defaultconf="default">
    <dependency org="net.glxn.qrgen" name="javase" rev="2.0"/>
  </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

Now typing `ant retrieve` will download and store 5 jars in `lib` subfolder.

**If you do not have a dependency manager**, here are the 5 jars urls you need to download manually and you need to move to a subfolder called `lib`:

- http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=net/glxn/qrgen/javase/2.0/javase-2.0.jar
- http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/zxing/javase/3.1.0/javase-3.1.0.jar
- http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/zxing/core/3.1.0/core-3.1.0.jar
- http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=net/glxn/qrgen/core/2.0/core-2.0.jar
- http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/jfree/jfreesvg/2.1/jfreesvg-2.1.jar

*I **strongly** advise you to use a java dependency manager if you wish one day to upgrade the revisions of the java libraries used in this code snippet.*

Next step is to use the following ruby **snip.rb** code in the same folder. :

```
require 'java'
%w[
  lib/core-2.0.jar
  lib/core-3.1.0.jar
  lib/javase-2.0.jar
  lib/javase-3.1.0.jar
  lib/jfreesvg-2.1.jar
].map &method(:require)

# this is the CRITICAL line to get it to work...
include_class 'net.glxn.qrgen.javase.QRCode' 

# get QR file from text using defaults
# this will write a file (example: QRCode7247556396487679822.png) in java.io.tmpdir as defined in your JVM
file = QRCode.from("Hello World").file()
p file.name

# get QR stream from text using defaults
# if we redirect the stream as a byte array, we can have a better file control
include_class 'java.io.FileOutputStream'
stream = QRCode.from("Hello World").stream()
fos = FileOutputStream.new("QRCode.png")
fos.write(stream.toByteArray())
fos.close()

# fun with VCards
include_class 'net.glxn.qrgen.core.vcard.VCard' 
johnDoe = VCard.new("John Doe")
johnDoe.setEmail("john.doe@example.org")
johnDoe.setAddress("John Doe Street 1, 5678 Doestown")
johnDoe.setTitle("Mister")
johnDoe.setCompany("John Doe Inc.")
johnDoe.setPhoneNumber("1234")
johnDoe.setWebsite("www.example.org")
stream = QRCode.from(johnDoe).stream()
fos = FileOutputStream.new("VCard.png")
fos.write(stream.toByteArray())
fos.close()

# all generated PNG can be decoded online using http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx
```

**Please note:** jruby and java.io.tmpdir do not play well together in this particular jar case, as any call to QRcode creation with `#file()` will store file in java.io.tmpdir, whereever it is located. You've little control on the file location.

So I modified the original code answer to use the stream instead and create files with finer control.

You can verify all files generated with this useful URL: http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx

Comment: i have no knowledge of java. can't we download jar file directly from git?? or is there any website that directly provides jar file for java library's like ruby toolbox site (https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) in ruby??

Comment: @SanjaySalunkhe no you can't directly download from git like you asked. You can either use a dependency manager from java (ivy or maven or gradle) or download manually the packages from maven. What you'll lose then is the possible miss of 1 or few jars to have the dependencies met. Let me build the download list at least for this case. Keep in mind to use a dependency manager from java if you've more integrations like this.

Comment: @SanjaySalunkhe the list with static urls of all jars needed has been added to the answer. Happy testing!

Comment: @SanjaySalunkhe it's been almost a week now: have you tested using the static urls I gave in the update? if too troublesome, I can cut a dedicated gem, but I believe on the integration of a 3rd party java library the answer is complete

Comment: Yes.. it worked for me... Thanks for your answer....sorry for late, was very busy... :)